# space between equation is not the same

Tags: equations

I wanted to write these equations:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[top=0.75in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}

$$
\Sigma F=ma:
\begin{cases}
 for(M): M\ddot x_1&=-kx_1+T-2k(x_1-x_3-r\theta)+F_1 \\
for(3m): 3m\ddot x_2&=F_2-T\\
for(m): m\ddot x_3&=-c\dot x-3-3kx_3+2k(x_1-x_3-r\theta)+F_3
\end{cases}
$$

\end{document}
```

But the space between equation is not the same!

EDITED:

How can I add numbering to that??

Comment: Don't use  `$$ … $$`, which is plain TeX syntax, and leads to bad spacing. Use for one-line displays`\[ … ]` instead. And add `\text{   }` around text inside display equations `for` is italic, with horizontal spacing like the product of three variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose this variant, based on `empheq` and `alignat`. You might want to consider the different lines as `subequations`:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[top=0.75in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
  \begin{empheq}[left ={\Sigma F=ma\colon \empheqlbrace}]{alignat = 2}%
  & \text{for $(M)$: } &M\ddot x_1 &=-kx_1+T-2k(x_1-x_3-r\theta)+F_1 \\
 & \text{for $(3m)$: }& \quad 3m\ddot x_2&=F_2-T\\
 & \text{for $(m)$: } & m\ddot x_3& =-c\dot x-3-3kx_3+2k(x_1-x_3-r\theta)+F_3
\end{empheq}
\end{subequations}

  \begin{empheq}[left ={\Sigma F=ma\colon \empheqlbrace}]{alignat = 2}%
  & \text{for $(M)$: } &M\ddot x_1 &=-kx_1+T-2k(x_1-x_3-r\theta)+F_1 \\
 & \text{for $(3m)$: }& \quad 3m\ddot x_2&=F_2-T\\
 & \text{for $(m)$: } & m\ddot x_3& =-c\dot x-3-3kx_3+2k(x_1-x_3-r\theta)+F_3
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

spacing is never good when consecutive equation blocks are grouped.
better results are usually obtained by using a multi-line environment,
perhaps `gather`, from `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[top=0.75in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}
\noindent
separate \verb+equation+s:
\begin{equation}
for(M): M\ddot x_1=-kx_1+T-2k(x_1-x_3-r\theta)+F_1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
for(3m): 3m\ddot x_2=F_2-T
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
for(m): m\ddot x_3=-c\dot x-3-3kx_3+2k(x_1-x_3-r\theta)+F_3
\end{equation}

\noindent
all three in a \verb+gather+:
\begin{gather}
for(M): M\ddot x_1=-kx_1+T-2k(x_1-x_3-r\theta)+F_1\\
for(3m): 3m\ddot x_2=F_2-T\\
for(m): m\ddot x_3=-c\dot x-3-3kx_3+2k(x_1-x_3-r\theta)+F_3
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

**Note:**
"for" should probably be marked as `\text{...}`, which will set the word in
the "usual" roman font.  (thanks to @Bernard for his comment; i wasn't paying
proper attention.)